# Rhel osbuild-composer system repository override is not working

Tags: rhel

As per document (https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/composing_a_customized_rhel_system_image/managing-repositories_composing-a-customized-rhel-system-image) tried to override the system repository with custom base url  . But blueprint depsolve is showing error as below

##composer-cli blueprints depsolve  Test1-blueprint
2022-06-09 08:06:58,841: Test1-blueprint: This system does not have any valid subscriptions. Subscribe it before specifying rhsm: true in sources.

And with next service restart osbuild-composer does not start

ERROR: Info Error: Get "http://localhost/api/v1/projects/source/info/appstream": dial unix /run/weldr/api.socket: connect: connection refused

Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 0):

Having all manner of issues with this myself. A trawl of my /var/log/messages file, and it looks like, for me at least, osbuild-composer is failing to start due to the non existence of /etc/osbuild-composer/osbuild-composer.toml. Actual error is permission denied, but it doesnt exist..

This is on RHEL 8.5, and just updated to 8.6 this morning, and same problem

/edit Ive removed everything, and reverted to using the lorax backend, as per chapter 2.2 in the doc linked (same one I was following). My 'composer-cli compose types' command now at least works. Fingers crossed..

Comment: Yes , it works with lorax for me also.